# Одинаковые индексы файлов в ext2

Tags: linux, файловая-система, link

Узнал что на самом деле файловые имена и сами файлы напрямую не связаны. Сами файлы имен не имеют, у них есть только индексы. А файловая система(в данном случае `ext2`) связывает придуманные имена с индексами файла. И жесткие ссылки это два разных имени на один индекс, но жесткие ссылки создать на каталог нельзя. Зашел я в `/` и командой `ls -il` получил примерно следующие:

```
       1 dr-xr-xr-x 232 root root     0 июн 26 17:14 proc
16252929 drwx------   5 root root  4096 июн 26 17:12 root
.........................................................
       1 dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 июн 26 22:56 sys
```

Где первое число это индексный дескриптор. Получается у каталогов `proc` и `sys` один файл? Как такое возможно? Ведь жестких ссылок быть не должно, да и количество этих ссылок разные(`232` и `13`)

Comment: proc и sys это виртуальные каталоги. На самом деле их нет на диске.

Comment: Запустите, например, mount и посмотрите что и куда смонтировано. Кстати, у них ещё и размер нулевой.

Comment: @AlexeyTen они есть, ведь точка монтирования должна быть каталогом

Comment: Да, но после монтирования оригинального каталога не видно

Comment: Плохо написал, да

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что номера файловых дескрипторов (*inode*) уникальны только в пределах одной файловой системы (*ФС*) и для разных ФС они, само собой, могут повторяться.

В каталоги `/proc` и `/sys` обычно смонтированы виртуальные файловые системы linux, что по всей видимости и описано в случае в вопросе. И в `ls -i` отображает номера inode'ов корневых каталогов именно этих файловых систем для их точек монтирования.

Для того чтобы увидеть истинные номера inode этих каталогов в корневой ФС можно, например, просто отмонтировать вышеупомянутые каталоги (делать с осторожностью) или смонтировать корневую ФС в другое место:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/root
mount /dev/<MY_ROOT_DEVICE> /mnt/root
ls -li /mnt/root
```

Answer (score 0):

`mount` перекрывает не содержимое каталога, а сам католог новой ссылкой.
Ссылка 1 означает что надо обращаться к виртуальной файловой системе ядра (там еще dev/pts), ссылка 2 что там смонтирован жесткий диск.

Если эту точку отмонтировать, то лс покажет реальный индекс этого каталога.